# Where did I get the example code in Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I'm just new to Maven. I'm following the "[Maven in 5 Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)" on this website.

When I run 
`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`

I find that

[image]

is generated. However, where did I got this source code? From website or from downloaded **apache-maven-3.2.5-bin.zip**. Which command indicates the location to get source?

Comment: That come from the archetype plugin. Read about it. See it here: http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/

Comment: @JorgeCampos. Thanks, I will check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified by `-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart`, the data comes from the [Maven Quickstart Archetype](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-bundles/maven-archetype-quickstart/).

`mvn` retrieved it from the Central Repository ([`org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.maven.archetypes|maven-archetype-quickstart|1.1|maven-archetype)) when you ran that command. The [source code](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-bundles/maven-archetype-quickstart/source-repository.html) is at http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/archetypes/trunk/maven-archetype-quickstart/ .

Comment: Great. Another question. The "mvn package" will compile the entire source code?

Comment: Yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533828/what-does-mvn-install-in-maven-exactly-do .