# What exactly happens when you run mvn install?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I know that when you run `mvn install` it will compile, package, and copy the binaries in the local .m2 repository.

I recently created a maven project in intelliJ and ran `mvn install`.  I then checked the .m2 repository and the generated binaries were there.  When I tried to add a dependency to that newly created snapshot from another intelliJ project, they aren't being picked up.

1. Any idea what is missing?
2. Does anything happen in `mvn install` besides copying the new snapshot into .m2?

Comment: for the mvn install question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533828/what-does-mvn-install-in-maven-exactly-do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does mvn install in maven exactly do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533828/what-does-mvn-install-in-maven-exactly-do)

Answer (score 1):

`mvn dependency:tree` is usually the best tool for figuring out what's going on with dependencies.

Sometimes with IDE's they use their own repo or don't pick things up.  I'd generally do a sanity check mvn clean install from the command line to make sure things are working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the default lifecycle of maven. When you execute one phase - all previous phases are executed before it. So if you call `mvn install` previous 21 actions will run before `install` phase which is 22.

1. validate
2. initialize
3. generate-sources
4. process-sources
5. generate-resources
6. process-resources
7. compile
8. process-classes
9. generate-test-sources
10. process-test-sources
11. generate-test-resources
12. process-test-resources
13. test-compile
14. process-test-classes
15. test
16. prepare-package
17. package
18. pre-integration-test
19. integration-test
20. post-integration-test
21. verify
22. install
23. deploy

Comment: So instead of mvn clean install, its perfectly ok to use mvn install because clean phase always execute before install phase. Am I correct?

Comment: do you see clean in this list? There is another lifecycle for clean) Read this https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: @Dinusha, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work