# Maven: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundErrorexception, but jars are downloaded in .m2

Tags: java, linux, maven, tomcat

I have a tomcat project: `tomcat/webapps/Project`. That project makes use of `org.json` library, the dependency is written in `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
```

I have installed `maven` on my server and run this command, while in the `Project` directory:
`mvn install`

Then I checked `/root/.m2/repository/org/json/20180813` folder and the file `json-20180813.jar` is there!

However when I restart my server: `shutdown.sh` and try to make use of my app, the error is still there:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject`

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

**EDIT**: People pointed out the copying of the jar to `tomcat/lib` directory. I did it and it worked. However, I would also be interested in a more permanent solution, so that I wouldn't be forced to do this again with other jars in the future.

Comment: Try put this jar in your tomcat `lib` folder.

Comment: in your .m2/settings.xml, did you configure your localRepository?

Comment: @wenzi No, I don't think so. All I did was to run a programm to install Maven insetlf and that's about it.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html, maybe you can try the section "Simple Values" to let it pull from your local repository

Comment: if you use `<packaging>war</packaging>` in your pom file, it will package all your dependencies in the war, then you could just deploy that war file to your tomcat environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command `mvn install` will compile and install your project library to your local repository. In addition it will download and copy any dependencies there also, under that `.m2/repository` directory. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10533828/6413377) for more detailed explanation about `mvn install`.

However it has nothing to do with Tomcat or deploying applications to a Tomcat instance. It will not make any libraries available for Tomcat directly.

To make Tomcat use any library there are at least these two options:

1. You can add them as a dependency in `war` packaged project. So, you might have something wrong in your `pom.xml` if you already deploy a WAR and still the library does not seem to be found by Tomcat.
2. As suggested in other answer you can manually copy the dependencies to the `tomcat/lib` directory and make the dependency in POM `<scope>provided</scope>` to prevent those to be packaged to the WAR.

The latter option might be sensible if you do not want to deploy monolithic - say 100MB - war every 5 minutes when developing especialy if doing it over network.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your `.jar` file into your tomcat folder `lib`, it will work like a charm!

Comment: Thank you, it did work. However, I can't do it with every single jar out there manually, can I? Is there a way to keep the jars in .m2 and let tomcat know of it?