# MI test Module-Transport error on installation

Tags: maven, wso2, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to install micro-integrator from https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator. I followed the instructions, but encountered an error. The below log shows the error message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project org.wso2.carbon.ei.tests.transport: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ? -

Comment: Can you explain, what do you mean by `install`? And which instructions do you follow? I'm asking, because to run you need only to download and unzip the latest release from: https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/releases 
(look for assets) and run as described here:
https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/installation/install_in_vm_binary/#prerequisites

Comment: Clone or download the source code from this repository (https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator).
Run the maven command mvn clean install from the root directory of the repository.
The generated Micro Integrator distribution can be found at micro-integrator/distribution/target/wso2mi-<version>.zip.

Comment: That is rather building product from source using maven, not a `installation` as in software. You can read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533828/what-does-mvn-install-in-maven-exactly-do